# MemoryStream class namespace

Tags: c#

I am trying to use memorystream calss to convert my byte array to an image. But I am missing a directive or namespace that this class belongs to, what dll or .net assemby I need to include in my project to be able to use it.

Comment: Here's a tip: If you get the red squiggly lines under a class that is not recognized, try moving the caret (the edit cursor) to that word and pressing Ctrl+. You'll get a small menu that includes a command to add the needed namespace, assuming your project references a library that defines that symbol.

Comment: Advertisement: Here is top search result using http://bing.com for "MemoryStream" Microsoft provides to you in hope to answer such questions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx. It also includes complete sample...

Comment: Is there a reason why you couldn't look it up in [the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) yourself? Below the inheritance hierarchy you see the namespace and assembly you need.

Comment: Just to add to the MSDN suggestions: MSDN documentation lists the namespace of each type as well as its assembly.  In this case, `Namespace: System.IO; Assembly:  mscorlib (in mscorlib.dll)`

Comment: @phoog, unfortunately one can't close SO question as exact duplicate of MSDN article :)

Comment: note that C# is Case Sensitive

Comment: I have never wanted to post LMGTFY more than I do Right now.  When I google search the exact title of this post, the title of the first result is: `MemoryStream Class (System.IO) - MSDN - Microsoft`

Answer (score 6):

at the top of your code file:

```
using System.IO;
```

If you're using Visual Studio, there's actually an easy way to check for this.

If you click on `MemoryStream`, you might see a small blue rectangle to the left of it.

- Hover your mouse over that rectangle, and a button might appear.
- If you click on that button, you will be given hints about how to solve the error
- one of those hints should be **"Using System.IO"**.  click on that and it should add it automatically.

This works for other class libraries too.

Comment: ok: guys i m very new to the whole .net thing, I have been using powerbuilder for quite a few years now and I just started using visual studio and .net I have some prior experience in j2ee but very little. I appologize if I asked a question that may sound very basic to you all but I just do not go ahead and post question i try to do my research first and that is what I will always do.

Answer (score 3):

Try with this:--

```
using System.IO;
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.IO` IIRC

Just to make it 30 chars

Comment: Never mind, I had to write something extra to make it 30 characters to post.

Comment: Don't you think that the 30 characters has some reason? Just the plain solution is no good answer. Never!

Comment: yes, but not for this question